# How to find out xpath of elements in client server based web application in IE11?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, automated-tests, internet-explorer-11, browser-automation

I am trying to find out xpath in web application with developer tools of IE but developer tools not open due to security reasons in IE. so now i am facing problem to find out xpath of elements in IE. If anyone have any idea then please help me its appreciable.

Comment: You can use other Browser like Chrome to find out the xpaths or selectors and then use it. Refer Image if you want to find out how to find the Xpaths or selector on Chrome => http://postmyimage.com/img2/293_Screen_Shot_2019_02_13_at_14.5.png

Comment: Thanks for response but site restricted to all browser except IE 6 or above. it work only in IE browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use F12 and [MRI](http://westciv.com/mri/) to find the elements by xpath in IE 11, more details, please check [this article](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxNZ0dfg4OQ).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in my website not allow me to open MRI. So in this case how can i find xpath?